# How to run bcp commands one by one

Tags: bcp, errorlevel, sql-server-bcp

i want to execute 15 "bcp commands" one by one in only one single batch file/script..
Every command should process or execute only after previous command was successfully executed..
if in any case a command fails to execute..the script should be stop execution...

i tried this..but i didn't get sufficient output what i need..

```
bcp.exe "select * from OrderXpress.dbo.Customers where CustId < 1000" queryout "D:\Customer.dat" -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n  

IF %ERRORLEVEL% > 0 ( PAUSE )

bcp.exe OrderXpress.dbo.Customers out "D:\Customer2.dat" -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n 

IF %ERRORLEVEL% > 0 ( PAUSE )

bcp.exe OrderXpress.dbo.Orders out "D:\Orders.dat" -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n 

IF %ERRORLEVEL% > 0 ( PAUSE )
```

Comment: Why don't u try RaiseError in case you want to stop executing command

Comment: i dont know much about batch script.. im a newbee... can u give me a sample code if u dont mind @nishantMittal

Comment: But for that u should logged in as Admin otherwise RAISEERROR() call itself will get fail and the script will continue executing....

Comment: raiseerror() ..???
Im working on batch files script not sql script...

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are missing is that the total script stops. Your `pause` command at the moment holds the script temporarily, but not the full script.

You should use a label to jump to instead. In the below script I added the label `:error_happened` to jump to in case of an error. In case there is no error, then the command `goto :EOF` will skip past the `:error_happened` label.

```
bcp.exe "select * from OrderXpress.dbo.Customers where CustId < 1000" queryout "D:\Customer.dat" -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n  
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error_happened

bcp.exe OrderXpress.dbo.Customers out "D:\Customer2.dat" -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error_happened

bcp.exe OrderXpress.dbo.Orders out "D:\Orders.dat" -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error_happened

goto :EOF

:error_happened
echo,
echo An error has occurred. Script stopped
echo
pause
```

A remark must be made however on the errorlevel that comes out of BCP. In case a data row is not exported correctly, then I am not sure on what happens with the errorlevel. I know that on import a row error does not lead to problems. See also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.tools/qzpWuZzJnr4

I have a workaround using the -e parameter to check for errors. The script would then be:

```
bcp.exe "select * from OrderXpress.dbo.Customers where CustId < 1000" queryout "D:\Customer.dat" -e errors.txt -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n  
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error_happened
call :check_errorfile

bcp.exe OrderXpress.dbo.Customers out "D:\Customer2.dat" -e errors.txt -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error_happened
call :check_errorfile

bcp.exe OrderXpress.dbo.Orders out "D:\Orders.dat" -e errors.txt -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error_happened
call :check_errorfile

goto :EOF

:check_errorfile
if exist errors.txt (
    FOR %%A IN (errors.txt) DO (
        if %%~zA GTR 0 (
        goto error_happened
        ) else (
        del errors.txt
        )
    )
)
exit /b

:error_happened
echo,
echo An error has occurred. Script stopped
echo
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this...

BEGIN TRY
    bcp.exe "select * from OrderXpress.dbo.Customers where CustId < 1000" queryout "D:\Customer.dat" -S localhost -U sa -P Sa12345 -E -n

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

```
DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(1000)

SET @msg = ERROR_MESSAGE()

RAISERROR(@msg,16,0)
```

END CATCH

Comment: This seems to be a combination of SQL and batch script